# Error on git push after adding external file to local repository

Tags: gitlab

i am trying to add a external file in my local gitlab repository and trying to push into my gitlab repo.. I am getting the following error

> hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
>   hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
>   hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
>   hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
>   hint:
>   hint:   git submodule add  capita-client
>   hint:
>   hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
>   hint: index with:
>   hint:
>   hint:   git rm --cached capita-client
>   hint: 
>   hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. Just check for .git file inside the external file.  if it's there then Delete it.